# How to add custom access control with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

Base access restriction works like:

- access to user is restricted if they have not appropriate Role.
- access to application is restricted if it isn't subscribed to API.

new access restriction mode should be added:

- access to user is restricted if they come through XXX application but
  they don't have XXXuser Role

Comment: What have you tried? What's your challenge?

Comment: I tried to use a role-based and service-provider-control policy. It works always, and this is not what we need. Ie whether it is possible to use instead of a role, for example, subscription to the application. And is it possible to use variables to be able to adorn and not to use particular cases?